# Consistency of Biased Estimators

Tags: random-variables, statistical-inference, parameter-estimation, law-of-large-numbers

In Statistical Inference, we were taught this theorem,

Consider an estimator $T_n$ of population parameter $\theta$, using $n$ samples. $T_n$ is a Consistent Estimator of $\theta$ if     $$E[T_n] \to \theta \text{ and $Var(T_n) \to 0$}$$

However the converse of the above is not true. To show this, I made the following estimator of $\mu$. Let $X_1, X_2...X_n$ be random samples from a population with finite mean $\mu$ and varaice $\sigma^2$. Denote the sample mean by $\bar{X_n}$.

$$T_n = \bar{X_n} + n^2Y_n$$
Where $$Y_n \sim Ber(\frac{1}{n})$$
and $Y_i$'s are independent of the sample $X_1, X_2...X_n$. It's clear $E[T_n] = \mu + n$. Clearly, $E[T_n] \not\to \mu$. Using the Weak Law of Large numbers.
$$(1 - \frac{\sigma^2}{n \epsilon^2}) \leq P(|\bar{X}_n -
\mu| \leq \epsilon) \leq 1$$
Noting that $Y_n$ is $0$ with probability $(1 - \frac{1}{n})$, and in that case, $T_n | (Y_n = 0) =\bar{X}_n$. We can say

$$(1 - \frac{\sigma^2}{n \epsilon^2})(1 - \frac{1}{n}) \leq P(|T_n -
\mu| \leq \epsilon) \leq 1$$
Taking the limit $n \to \infty$, we get $T_n$ is a consistent estimator of $\mu$.

Can someone produce an example purely using the samples (not like the $Y_n$ I used here, as I'm not sure how we'll generate the "randomness" $Y_n$ assures)?

Answer (score 0):

An easy example is to sample from a Pareto distribution with parameter $\alpha \in (1, 2]$. In this way the sample mean $\bar{X}_n$ is an unbiased and consistent estimator whose variance does not tend to $0$. Indeed:

- By the (weak) Law of Large Numbers, since $\alpha > 1$, the sample mean converges in probability to the expected value. Hence the estimator is consistent
- $\mathbb{E}[\bar{X}_n] = \mathbb{E}[X_1] = \theta$, i.e. the estimator is unbiased
- $\text{Var}(\bar{X}_n) = \text{Var}(X_1)/n = \infty$, hence the variance does no converge to zero if $n \to \infty$

Comment: do we not need finite variance to apply  WLLN? The WLLN uses the Chebychev Inequality to be proved.

Comment: no, it is not required. Some texts state the theorem with common finite variance (and maybe no correlation) to simplify the proof, but the theorem still holds with infinite variance. It is instead fundamental in the Central Limit Theorem (CLT)